# What happens if a mage dies with multiple clones?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells

Imagine that a PC has created multiple clones, through the casting of [*clone*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/clone), each matured.

What happens when that PC dies and declares his soul willing to go to each clone? I understand that *the character* could avoid this problem by declaring himself only willing to go to one particular clone, but if he did not, what would happen?

Would he occupy his first clone? The most recent? A random one? One of the player's choosing? DM's choosing? Or is it just DM perview?

Comment: Are you looking for answers other than 'hilarity ensues' - I ask because the *tone* at a given table will have some influence on how this plays out.

Comment: Well I know by RAW the soul can only occupy one, @KorvinStarmast, since the soul isn’t free when it occupies a clone, but I don’t know what order it would go in.

Comment: Welll.....by lore....... in FR, the wizard Manshoon had created over a dozen clones of himself and when he was slain, _all of them_ woke up, and _all of them_ were convinced they were the Real Manshoon. Naturally, they all set about trying to kill one another in a shadow war that lasted about a century...IIRC, there is theoretically only one left...but he's been making clones again. So, yes...'hilarity ensues' may not be a RAW supported answer, but it is definitely a lore-supported answer.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

### There's no RAW or RAI to limit which clone your soul goes to.

[Clone](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/clone) provides backup bodies for your soul. You cannot split your soul across multiple clones, but there are no rules or lore about issues with your soul traveling across distances. There's no instance of a soul travelling at a set speed, so there's no benefit, detriment, or limit to picking a clone based on location. The clone spell doesn't even limit you to using clones on the plane on which you died, suggesting the soul could travel through the planes to backup bodies.

> At any time after the clone matures, if the original creature dies, its soul transfers to the clone, provided that the soul is free and willing to return.

In this situation, where there are no limiting rules on which clone can be chosen, there is nothing to prevent a player from picking from any clone that has matured. Souls have been shown to be intelligent enough to make decisions, so the player would retain control over their soul, and it wouldn't be a DM decision (unless you leave it up to them for story purposes).

Answer (score 5):

### It's your choice (sort of)

Obviously, you can't split your soul between clones. Let's have a look at the ruling for resurrections:

The player immediately knows the alignment/identity of anyone trying to bring him back to life and may choose whether or not to return.

I would interpret this as each clone being a separate caller and the player can choose if he wants to come back in a specific one, as long as there was a distinguishing feature between them, as the situation around them is not portrayed. This means that if you can tell them apart, it is the player's choice.