Using clone spell without a target's knowledge to trap them
I've been trying to theory-craft a D&D 5e strategy that uses the spell Clone to kidnap and imprison someone. The rough idea is to secretly clone a target, set a trap to effectively imprison the clone as it revives, then kill that target. The target's soul then transfers to the clone as long as it is free and willing.
The part I'm unsure about is the willing/unwilling aspect. Keep in mind the target wouldn't have any prior knowledge of the clone, and the transfer happens the exact moment they die. How much information would the creature being revived actually have when they decide whether or not to refuse the revival. Do they simply know they're being revived, or can they determine things like who the spellcaster is, what spell is being used, what body they're reviving into, the body's location, the body's condition, etc...

If you want this question to stay open, please scope it to one problem.  As you have written it, you have an "idea generation" post which does not fit the SE format.  If you edit out the last two sentences, your question will be tightly scoped for one novel application of the clone spell.  Welcome to RPGSE.  The [Tour], [Help], [Ask] and [Answer] provide solid guidance on how to use and get the most from this site.  Also, the Clone spell has been in D&D since about 1975; it is slightly different in each edition of the game. Please specify the edition of the game you are asking about.

Somewhat related on a character being reincarnated in a manner they didn't choose: Does a soul being resurrected know what spell is being used?

I'll try to re-word the post so the question is more pointed

Per your revisions, I think this is good for us to answer. I've voted to reopen.

You might consider supplying a little context regarding the game you're planning on using this in.  Are you a player or the DM?  Is the target a PC or an NPC?

In the scenario I imagined, the NPC spellcaster would trade some service to one of the players in exchange for the flesh component to the Clone spell. If that PC ever died the party would find they can't resurrect him and don't have any leads to find him, leading that player to roll a new character. Later they possibly encounter the clone as a servant to the npc spellcaster. I'm interested in both cases though.

Doing this to a player character is something I'd discourage. It goes against the player's agency over their character. However, some players would jump at the idea of having this kind of secret to spring on their fellow players, if given the option. Same with replacing a PC with a doppelganger: cool when working together, no fun when it's done to you without permission.

They know this:

A soul can't be returned to life if it doesn't wish to be. A soul knows the name, alignment, and patron deity (if any) of the character attempting to revive it and might refuse to return on that basis. For example, if the honorable knight Sturm Brightblade is slain and a high priestess of Takhisis (god of evil dragons) grabs his body, Sturm might not wish to be raised from the dead by her. Any attempts she makes to revive him automatically fail. If the evil cleric wants to revive Sturm to interrogate him, she needs to find some way to trick his soul, such as duping a good cleric into raising him and then capturing him once he is alive again.

DMG: page 24, "Bringing Back the Dead"
For your plan, they know "the name, alignment, and patron deity (if any)" of the wizard who cast the Clone spell. Based on that, the DM needs to decide if they choose to return or not.

I don't think it's that clear cut. The Clone spell is Instantaneous; there is no one "attempting" to revive them when they actually die, they're just mystically (but not magically, cause Instantaneous duration) tied to their clone and their soul has the option to transfer. I could definitely see a DM using this as the basis for a ruling, but it would be a ruling, not a clear and unambiguous rule. You could equally well say all they know is that there is a body immediately available to their soul, with zero other information, and have them choose on that basis.

"A soul can't be returned to life if it doesn't wish to be" is pretty clear cut.

I'm still not sure if the section of DMG you referenced applies in this context. The opening paragraph of Bringing Back The Dead defines death as the soul leaving the body,  leaving the Material Plane, traveling the Astral Plane, and finally arriving at an Outer Plane. It then defines bringing someone back from the dead as retrieving the soul from said Outer Plane and returning it to its body. In the case of the Clone spell, the soul transfers to the clone without ever leaving the Prime Material Plane.

The clone spell requires the target to die. If you didn't die then the spell didn't trigger. As written all you describe happens in an instant.

@ShadowRanger Revivify is also instantaneous and there is no question that it is bringing someone back from the dead.

@TigerGuy It can be argued that revivify operates before the soul departs. (I have an answer along those lines somewhere, about revivify).

@TigerGuy: That... has nothing to do with my argument? I'm saying that Clone being instantaneous means that there is no caster at the time the soul transfers. Revivify brings someone back as part of the casting, Clone creates a clone, but doesn't actually do anything with the soul at the moment of casting, and officially, the magic is no longer active when the subject dies and their soul has the option to transfer, so there is, arguably, no caster and therefore none of the information from the DMG on what the subject knows is relevant.

@DaleM: Yeah, I agree they get a choice. I'm arguing they may be making that choice with less information than normal, because there is no one actively casting a spell that returns them to life at the moment they make this decision. They could presumably infer that they had been Cloned (unless through some weird combination of abilities, they could have a contingent Revivify in place), simply because they had the option to come back to life immediately upon dying, but they'd be in the dark as to who had cloned them, because no one is actively bringing them back to life at that moment.

@ShadowRanger where in the quote does it mention a spell?

@DaleM: Casting a spell is one mechanism through which someone could make the "attempt" mentioned in the quote. "Attempt" implies an active effort of some kind; casting a spell is one way of doing this. The person who cast Clone could themselves be dead when this finally happens, and it wouldn't affect anything, so they're clearly not "attempting" anything to revive the character.

Found a related article for reference: https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/141441/what-happens-if-a-mage-dies-with-multiple-clones A wizard who has created multiple clones can choose which one to revive into, meaning he can tell the clone spells apart. In this particular case he was the caster for each clone spell. I think that would imply that, even if you know who cast the spell, there would need to be some additional way to differentiate between seperate clone spells.

@JeremyKeasbey: That's one interpretation from your link. They could equally well Manshoon into multiple clones at once and go crazy in the process (Manshoon was a 2E-era character who had this happen; the rules discourage this interpretation, but have fun!). Or go to the closest one. Or enter one at random. Or enter the most recently created one old enough to accept the soul (or the oldest one!). The spell doesn't even begin to contemplate multiple clones, so it's pure DM fiat there. The top answer says the player chooses, but I see no reason to prefer that interpretation over any other.

An educated character can deduce that they have been cloned, but they receive no other information to guide their decision
There aren't many ways to be instantly returned to life upon death. Clone is one, and a Contingency-triggered Revivify (which don't appear on the same spell lists, so it would be highly unusual, and the former has a target of Self, so you'd know if you'd done it to yourself) is the other that comes to mind off-hand.
So by the mere fact that they're coming back to life immediately, if they are aware of the existence of the Clone spell (not automatic; wizards with a high enough level to cast it are incredibly rare, and I would not assume non-magical characters would be familiar with it, especially details like it taking effect on death, rather than just being how wizards stay alive forever), they'd know they'd been cloned.
But unlike with normal magic to restore the dead to life, Clone fails a key condition that would give them more information:

A soul knows the name, alignment, and patron deity (if any) of the character attempting to revive it and might refuse to return on that basis.

The Clone spell does not attempt to revive you at all. The Clone spell does one thing: Create the clone tied to your soul. The duration is Instantaneous, and there is no official magic in effect after that point, just like there is no magic in effect after any other Instantaneous duration spell (just like any fires set by Fireball keep burning, even if they're subjected to Dispel Magic immediately afterwards, and Detect Magic would not be able to identify the Evocation magic that started them). At the time you die, months later, no one is taking any action to revive you, there is, in fact, no active magic at all, just "the background magic that is part of the D&D multiverse's physics" that allows the soul transfer, ergo, no one is "attempting to revive you".
As such, you have no information about who is attempting to bring you back (because no one is). All you know is that you have the option to return to life immediately upon death, and assuming you have not cloned yourself, nor cast a contingent Revivify, and you are aware of the existence of, and have a familiarity with the mechanics of the Clone spell (for non-arcane casters with no prior exposure to the idea during the campaign, an Arcana roll might be appropriate), you could deduce that someone else had cloned you, but that's it.

This may seem trivial, but could you clarify whether the target can't identify the caster or recognizes there isn't a caster?

@JeremyKeasbey: I'd categorize this as something that depends on character knowledge. If you've been resurrected before, or have a grounding in religion that covered it (read: Roll a Religion check), you might know that you'd normally get some information about the caster, and would recognize the lack of information as informative in and of itself, and would likely recognize that there is no caster. If you lacked that knowledge (no personal experience and failed the Religion check), you might not know that anything is missing in the first place, so it would be "can't identify the caster".

Just occurred to me, you most likely wouldn't know who the spellcaster is, but would know it's a revival into a clone.
Game developers would have 2 practical gameplay reasons for giving players the option not to revive:

The clone spell requires 3000g worth of material components to cast, including a diamond worth 1000g, and the clone takes 4 months in-game to become usable. If you have a nearby party member who could cast revivify (which only take a 500g diamond to cast) players would obviously choose not to waste their clone revival

If you died in combat, reviving in the clone would make you impossible to revive mid-combat with revivify. You'd end up separated from the party, leaving behind all your equipment.


RP-wise it makes sense that you'd treat the capsule holding the clone as the caster. In that case you wouldn't know which spellcaster created the clone, but you would definitely realize it was a clone spell.

Sadly, if this is the case, it kinda makes the clone-kidnapping strategy impossible

The caster is the caster of the spell, not the storage capsule.
