How does Wild Shape interact with the clone spell?
Are there any interesting results from cloning a druid in Wild Shape? What form does the clone take? If it takes the form of a  beast, could the druid be trapped in beast form, or would they be able to revert to human form?

related https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/212887/using-clone-spell-without-a-targets-knowledge-to-trap-them

The clone would be a Druid in beast form, not just a beast with a Druid's soul trapped inside, and thus could revert to their original form
Firstly, although the clone spell makes a copy of the "living creature", if we assume that it wouldn't "see through" the Wild Shape ability (since it's not an illusion, the druid really is a beast at that point in time) and would create a clone of the druid's current beast form...
Wild Shape says:

You can stay in a beast shape for a number of hours equal to half your druid level (rounded down). You then revert to your normal form ...

So one could say that the cloned beast would also revert to the Druid's original form after however many number of hours, well before it's incubation period of 120 days. However, you could also argue that the clone isn't a Druid, it's just a clone of the Druid's current form, so it wouldn't revert the same way a Druid would.
If we say that the clone doesn't revert during incubation and remains as a beast...
The clone spell says:

The clone is physically identical to the original and has the same personality, memories, and abilities, but none of the original's equipment.

Since the "beast" would have the same abilities (among other things), that would include their Druid class features, so since it was due to a class feature that the Druid was a beast at the time when they were cloned, that Druid would presumably have the ability to revert to their original form if they wished.
It isn't clear what would happen with regards to the "timer", since the cloned body has been a beast for longer than "a number of hours equal to half your druid level", so a DM might rule that the druid instantly reverts, or it might be that the timer is "reset" upon the Druid's soul entering the body, so that the Druid would revert automatically "a number of hours equal to half your druid level" after they "wake up" in their new body.

This is a good answer. I'll wait a little while to see if anyone else has anything to say, but am happy with it so far. What do you think about odd nuances, like "any equipment gets merged into wildshape" vs "clone doesn't have equipment" clauses? I guess it would be too cheesy if equipment could be duplicated through wildshape cloning.

Yeah, there's no way the equipment would be cloned, because the clone spell explicitly calls that out, and I don't see any DM ruling otherwise. That sound seem pretty cheesy (I know one of my players would at least try their luck with that, though...)
